# RDLC Layout showing the correct number of lines but no data

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-nav

As title, I have created a dataset in NAV2015. I have put a RDLC layout over the top and for some reason the data in the columns will not show. Although the correct number of lines are coming through. So the report is looking at the right place.

The expression used is:

=Fields!CustomerName.Value

and CustomerName maps to a field in my database.

Please could someone offer some insight as to why this is? I am using NAV2015 and SQL report Builder.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
Data Type   Data Source Name    Include Caption
DataItem    Service Item Line   <Service Item Line> No
    Column  "Service Item Line"."Customer Name" CustomerName    Yes
    Column  "Serial No."    SerialNo_   Yes
    DataItem    Service Line    <Service Line>  No
DataItem    Service Invoice Header  <Service Invoice Header>    No
    Column  "Service Invoice Header"."Ship-to Name" CustomerName_inv    No
    Column  "Service Invoice Line"."Service Item Serial No."    SerialNo_inv    No
    DataItem    Service Invoice Line    <Service Invoice Line>  No
```

The XML can be found here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32233444/Reports/50100.rdl

Comment: Hi, sorry but that's not enough. RDLC can be very tricky. If you can attach the report object in txt and the dataset in xml I'm more than happy to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "over the top"? You've overwritten a standard layout? Perhaps you're missing the list that sits at the back of the report (and everything sits in) that iterates through the data.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated with more details.

Comment: I'd want to check the lines being sent to the RLDC. Do you have a NAV text object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest workaround may be to delete your layout and use the "layout suggestion" which will create a working RDLC layout (though not pretty!).

If that report still returns blank, then it's a filtering issue on your report and no lines are coming through from Service Item Line, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said in running a suggested layout and immediately spotted my problem. I am pulling from 2 sets of tables onto the same line, and was not showing enough information to get the results I wanted. By concatenating the data it now works as I expected.